# Problem combining fouriernc with tgschola

Tags: fonts, math-mode, packages

I have recently found out that tgschola and fouriernc actually have different font sizes (at least on my MiKTeX installation). 12pt fouriernc seems to be roughly equivalent to 11.2pt tgschola. The problem now arises when you I try to combine these fonts for text+math. The result looks inconsistent since I have specified 11.2pt fontsize in the KOMA class. [image]

Here's the MWE:

```
%\documentclass[fontsize=12pt,oneside,DIV=12,a4paper]{scrreprt}
\documentclass[fontsize=11.2pt,oneside,DIV=12,a4paper]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{fouriernc}
\usepackage{tgschola}

\begin{document}
This is $n_i$ a $r_{[0]}$ Test.
\end{document}
```

Is there a way to assign different font sizes to these two packages or are there any other solutins to this problem? Maybe I'm missing something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can load `tgschola` at a slightly reduced size:

```
\documentclass[fontsize=11.2pt,oneside,DIV=12,a4paper]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{fouriernc}
\usepackage[scale=0.92]{tgschola}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}
% Draw a rule to mark the x-height
\makebox[0pt][l]{\color{green!70}\vrule height\dimexpr 1ex+0.2pt depth -1ex width \textwidth}%
This is $n_i$ a $r_{[0]}$ Test.
\end{document}
```

[image]