# Change Math fonts

Tags: fonts

I am trying to change the standard Latex fonts to TexGyreSchola for the entire document.  I have done so successfully for the main text by including

```
\usepackage{tgschola}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

in the preamble.  However, I have not been able to change the math counterpart.  If anyone has some experience on this, I would appreciate it very much.

Comment: Which fonts do you want to use? You need to pick text and maths fonts which work well together, and it is generally best to think about maths first as there are fewer of those than there are text fonts.

Comment: Please take a look [here](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/mathfonts.html) for examples of font combinations for maths. If you click on a font, you can get more information, including the code needed to use it in your document.

Comment: I would like both text and math to be TexGyreSchola. I have installed both, but I am not sure how to invoke the maths.

Comment: What's your platform?  Can you use `xelatex` ?

Answer (score 2):

The `fouriernc` package provides a set of math fonts compatible with New Century Schoolbook.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fouriernc}
\usepackage{tgschola}

\begin{document}

A formula $a=b-c+\sqrt{2}$

\textit{italic} 123
\end{document}
```

[image]

Since TeX Gyre Schola is at a size slightly bigger than `fouriernc`, it's better to scale the text font down (see [Problem combining fouriernc with tgschola](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/148997/problem-combining-fouriernc-with-tgschola))

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fouriernc}
\usepackage[scale=0.92]{tgschola}

\begin{document}

A formula $a=b-c+\sqrt{2}$

\textit{italic} 123$123$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Niko As egreg himself explained in some of his previous answers, it is much better to scale down a bit the tgfschola fonts using the option \usepackage[scale=0.92]{tgfschola} to get a perfect match with the math fonts fouriernc. See here for instance http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/148999/9255.

Comment: @brunoh Indeed!